# Logical volume back up and recovery using dd

Tags: dd

I have created a snapshot for a logical volume as below:

```
sudo lvcreate -v -s -L 100M -n lv2_snap /dev/vg1/lv2
```

I'm able to mount that snapshot, check the files, looks good.

Then, take a disk dump of the snapshot:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/vg1/lv2_snap of=lv2_snap.dd
```

After that, I try to recover from the disk dump:

```
sudo dd if=lv2_snap.dd of=/dev/vg1/lv2_snap
```

Then I try to mount the `lv2_snap`, I got

```
can't ready superblock. 
sudo mount /dev/vg1/lv2_snap snap_recover/
mount: /home/wxue/snap_recover: can't read superblock on /dev/mapper/vg1-lv2_snap
```

.

Try to recover super block from back up does not work:

```
sudo mke2fs -n /dev/vg1/lv2_snap
mke2fs 1.44.6 (5-Mar-2019)
Creating filesystem with 512000 1k blocks and 128016 inodes
Filesystem UUID: 5078cdaa-b0fc-42ca-a173-94c4dcc0a739
Superblock backups stored on blocks:
        8193, 24577, 40961, 57345, 73729, 204801, 221185, 401409

sudo e2fsck -b 8193 /dev/vg1/lv2_snap
e2fsck 1.44.6 (5-Mar-2019)
e2fsck: Invalid argument while trying to open /dev/vg1/lv2_snap
```

How to recover from dd file?

Adding lvm version:

```
$sudo lvm version
  LVM version:     2.02.176(2) (2017-11-03)
  Library version: 1.02.145 (2017-11-03)
  Driver version:  4.39.0
  Configuration:   ./configure --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --includedir=${prefix}/include --mandir=${prefix}/share/man --infodir=${prefix}/share/info --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var --disable-silent-rules --libdir=${prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --libexecdir=${prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --runstatedir=/run --disable-maintainer-mode --disable-dependency-tracking --exec-prefix= --bindir=/bin --libdir=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --sbindir=/sbin --with-usrlibdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --with-optimisation=-O2 --with-cache=internal --with-clvmd=corosync --with-cluster=internal --with-device-uid=0 --with-device-gid=6 --with-device-mode=0660 --with-default-pid-dir=/run --with-default-run-dir=/run/lvm --with-default-locking-dir=/run/lock/lvm --with-thin=internal --with-thin-check=/usr/sbin/thin_check --with-thin-dump=/usr/sbin/thin_dump --with-thin-repair=/usr/sbin/thin_repair --enable-applib --enable-blkid_wiping --enable-cmdlib --enable-cmirrord --enable-dmeventd --enable-dbus-service --enable-lvmetad --enable-lvmlockd-dlm --enable-lvmlockd-sanlock --enable-lvmpolld --enable-notify-dbus --enable-pkgconfig --enable-readline --enable-udev_rules --enable-udev_sync

$uname -a
Linux WVM 5.0.0-21-generic #22-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 2 13:27:33 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Please run `sudo lvm version` and add the output to your question by editing it https://askubuntu.com/posts/1165995/edit

Comment: Please also run `uname -a` and add the output to your question.

Comment: If you chose to recreate the snapshot, please make sure to allocate enough space for it. If the snapshot logical volume becomes full, it will be unusable. Please do not use `dd` to backup the snapshot. Just use `tar -c` to create `tar.gz` file, move it to destination and use `tar -x` to extract it. Then please follow the steps in the answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1166020/968501 . Make sure you change the snapshot name part in the commands according to the new snapshot's name.

Comment: Your LVM version and kernel version all seem okay and should support this operation. The snapshot however might need to be recreated allocating more space to it. It shows the snapshot is 100% full in the `lvs` output you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some more inform over logical volume, I try to play with thin-pool and cache

```
sudo lvs
  LV        VG  Attr       LSize   Pool      Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  cache     vg1 Cwi---C--- 100.00m
  cache1    vg1 Cwi---C--- 100.00m
  lv2       vg1 owi-aotz-- 500.00m thin-pool        4.97
  lv2_snap   vg1 swi-I-s--- 100.00m           lv2    100.00
  lv3       vg1 Vwi-a-tz-- 500.00m thin-pool        0.00
  lv4       vg1 -wi-a----- 500.00m
  lvol0     vg1 -wi-a-----   4.00m
  lvol2     vg1 Cwi---C--- 100.00m
  thin-pool vg1 twi-aotz-- 500.00m                  4.97   11.23
```

lv convert also failed with below:

```
sudo lvconvert --merge /dev/vg1/lv2_snap
  Unable to merge invalidated snapshot LV "lv2_snap".
```

Here's what I found, I can't restore to a snapshot logical volume, I have to create a new logical volume, then restore it.

```
sudo lvcreate -L 500M -n lv5 vg1
  WARNING: Sum of all thin volume sizes (1000.00 MiB) exceeds the size of thin pools (no free space in volume group).
  WARNING: You have not turned on protection against thin pools running out of space.
  WARNING: Set activation/thin_pool_autoextend_threshold below 100 to trigger automatic extension of thin pools before they get full.
  Logical volume "lv5" created.

$sudo dd if=lv2snap.dd of=/dev/vg1/lv5
sudo mount /dev/1024000+0 records in
1024000+0 records out
524288000 bytes (524 MB, 500 MiB) copied, 17.9297 s, 29.2 MB/s

$sudo mount /dev/vg1/lv5 snap_recover/
```